# fgets() error: "No source available for..."

Tags: c, debugging, fgets

when i start my program i give a input like this:

```
EKMFLGDQVZNTOWYHXUSPAIBRCJ 16
AJDKSIRUXBLHWTMCQGZNPYFVOE 4
BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO 21
ABCDEFGDIJKGMKMIEBFTCVVJAT
2
MCK
QMJIDOMZWZJFJR
ABC
ESTAMENSAGEMVAISERCIFRADA
```

The program reads each line and then executes some methods, but when it reaches the fifth line  ("2") it crasches with the error message : *"No source available for "0xb7e9f84f" "*
The code in that corresponds to that reading is the following:

```
fgets(cadeia1, 31, stdin);
int rPos1 = getRotationPos(cadeia1);
fgets(cadeia2, 31, stdin);
int rPos2 = getRotationPos(cadeia2);
fgets(cadeia3, 31, stdin);
int rPos3 = getRotationPos(cadeia3);
fgets(cadeiaRef, 26, stdin);

r1 = createRotor(r1, cadeia1, rPos1);
r2 = createRotor(r2, cadeia2, rPos2);
r3 = createRotor(r3, cadeia3, rPos3);
ref = createReflector(ref, cadeiaRef);
m->r1 = r1;
m->r2 = r2;
m->r3 = r3;
m->ref = ref;

char* messages; 
fgets(messages, 3, stdin);     ////////////////////// This is where it crashes
int nMessages = atoi(messages);
```

I would like to know whats wrong :s, thanks anyway!

Comment: We'll need more code.

Comment: At a rough guess, you have at least one bug.

Comment: Also, do a debug build next time - with all the symbols built-in.

Comment: Did you allocate space for messages?  In the code you show, messages isn't initialized, so fgets will probably be writing to a bad memory location.  If you post a complete runnable test case, you're more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: "No source available for ..." sounds like it might be an error message from a debugger. Are you running the program directly, or under a debugger?

Comment: edit: using messages[3] solved the problem

Comment: i was running it under a debugger, when running it normally it would just terminate without error message

Comment: Sure it fixed the current issue. But it will fail if your input is incorrect, or it contains a two-digit number.

Comment: i should also alocate memory, to prevent other problems

Comment: If the error message is from the debugger, you need to mention that in the question. The fact that the debugger can't find a source file is not likely to be relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not allocated space for messages (based on what you have posted).  You either need to allocate space (malloc function) or declare a character array before using.

For example:

```
 char messages[3];
 fgets(messages,3,stdin);
```

or

```
 char *messages;
 /* ask for memory */
 *message = malloc(3);
 fgets(messages,3,stdin);
 /* do some processing */
 /* release the memory back */
 free(messages);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're passing an uninitialized pointer to `fgets` change your code to

```
char messages[256]; // or w/e max length you have dictated.
fgets(...);
```

You're most likely corrupting memory.